# How to change background color in grub

Tags: boot, grub2, themes, configuration, plymouth

I use Ubuntu 12.04. I want to change grub's background color to black. I mean just background color, not background image. I can only find guides how to change the image. I tried some GUI software which had an option to change the colors, but unfortunately grub just ignored those changes.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Grub Customizer.  If you don't have it installed, you can install it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Once installed, and you open the applications,  go to Appearance settings, and change backgroun colour

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: that's the soft I tried and it didn't change the colors. But there is "to get colors working you have to select a background image". Do you know something about it?

Comment: You can add any image of our choice.  It can be a picture, or solid background color.

Comment: I use the KDE desktop so I am using http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=139643 instead of this one. Does this one suffer the same problem documented here, where GRUB update ignores the background colors out-of-the-box? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1027223